# Jquery-image-gallery: Without using any internal classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the script which i wrote that nakes the use of the class i.e. `UiUx3DSSVFlow`.
 Without hardcoding this internal class, how to make use of their parent `#thumbs`?

I should not any more make use of the specific classes in my script. In the future those classes could change to any other *class name*. I need the same functionality in another way without using the internal class names

HTML:

```
<!--Thumbs Image-->

<div id="thumbs">
    <div class="UiUx3DSSVFlow">
        <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nuvola2/48x48/actions/thumbnail.png">
    </div>
    <div class="UiUx3DSSVFlow">
        <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nuvola2/48x48/actions/thumbnail.png">
    </div>        
    <div id="Video" class="UiUx3DSSVFlow">
        <div class="video_gallery">     
           <div>
                <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/iwqoOfZf4hc" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="250" width="250"></iframe>
           </div>
         </div>
    </div>       
    <div id="Video" class="UiUx3DSSVFlow">
        <div class="video_gallery">     
            <div>
                <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/iwqoOfZf4hc" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="250" width="250"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
<p><a class="tprev" href="#">Prev</a>
<p><a class="tnext" href="#">Next</a>
```

CSS:

```
#thumbs{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100%;  
}   
#thumbs div{display:inline-block;   }    
#larger{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100%;
}    
#larger div{display:inline-block;  }
```

jQuery:

```
function thumbs(i,incr){
    var num_thumbs=2;
    if(i===null){
        i=$("#thumbs").prop('data-index'),
        i+=num_thumbs*incr;
    }
    i=Math.max(1,Math.min(i,$('#thumbs .UiUx3DSSVFlow').length-num_thumbs+1));
    $("#thumbs").prop('data-index',i);
    $('#thumbs .UiUx3DSSVFlow').hide();
    $('#thumbs .UiUx3DSSVFlow:nth-child(n+'+i+'):nth-child(-n+'+Number(i+num_thumbs-1)+')').show();
}

$("#thumbs").prop('data-index',1);
$([['next',1],['prev',-1]]).each(function(){
    var that=this;
    $('.t'+that[0]).click(function(){
        thumbs(null,that[1]);
    });

});
$('.tprev').click();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T657N/33/

Comment: you **cannot** have multiple *ID* inside your document. `#Video`

Comment: @roXon: Can you please send me an updated Jsfiddle demo please. I should not use the internal class too `UiUx3DSSVFlow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T657N/35/)*

*review your HTML, CSS knowledge before jumping into JS!*

- You cannot have multiple **ID** inside one document!
- A `div`  element (as it's by default a *block* element) does not need the `width:100%`;
- `display: inline-block` is best suitable and xbrowser for `<span>` elements, for other browsers you'll need to use some sort of hax like:

> display:inline-block;
>   *display:inline;
>   zoom:1;

HTML:

```
<div id="thumbs">
    <div>
        <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nuvola2/48x48/actions/thumbnail.png">
        <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nuvola2/48x48/actions/thumbnail.png">
    </div>
    <div>     
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/iwqoOfZf4hc" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="250" width="250"></iframe>
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/iwqoOfZf4hc" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="250" width="250"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

<p><a class="tprev" href="#">Prev</a>
<p><a class="tnext" href="#">Next</a>
```

CSS:

```
#thumbs{border:1px solid red;}
#thumbs div{display:inline;}
```

jQuery:

```
var $tDiv = $('#thumbs div');
var tDivsN = $tDiv.length;
var c = 0;

function display(){
    c= c===-1? tDivsN-1 : c%tDivsN;
    $tDiv.hide().eq(c).show();
}
display();

$('.tprev, .tnext').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var myCLass= $(this).hasClass('tnext') ? c++ : c--;
    display();
});
```

Comment: Can you help me I need to show 4images initially and onclick of next the other 4images should display  http://jsfiddle.net/T657N/43/

Comment: But the structure should be like this only jsfiddle.net/T657N/43

Comment: Could you please help me out brother on my structure please